# Apache POI : Create PPT Slide which contains Image & Text Both

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 3.16 version to create PPT. I am able to create simpel PPT using this library, but facing issue when creating slide with Title and Image and Content in body.

Below is my code snippet

```
//creating a presentation 
XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
List<XSLFSlideMaster> slideMasters = ppt.getSlideMasters();

XSLFSlideLayout layout = slideMasters.get(0).getLayout(SlideLayout.TITLE_AND_CONTENT);

//creating a slide in it 
XSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide(layout);

//reading an image
File image=new File("C://Users//Public//Pictures//Sample Pictures//Hydrangeas.jpg");

//converting it into a byte array
byte[] picture = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(image));

//adding the image to the presentation
XSLFPictureData idx = ppt.addPicture(picture, PictureType.PNG);

XSLFTextShape placeholder = slide.getPlaceholder(0);
placeholder.setText("New Title....");

XSLFTextShape placeholder1   = slide.getPlaceholder(1);
placeholder1.clearText();
placeholder1.setFillColor(new java.awt.Color(201, 201, 191));
       placeholder1.getSheet().createPicture(idx).getPictureData().getImageDimension().setSize(1, 1);
    placeholder1.appendText("Footer Generated", true);

   //creating a file object 
    File file=new File("C:\\addingimage.pptx");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

    //saving the changes to a file
    ppt.write(out);
    System.out.println("image added successfully");
    out.close();
```

I want to create a slide with Giving Titile as "Slide 1" and Body of slide will have Image (Which I can resize) and after after Image I need to have Image description or some other content.

Thank you for your all answers.

Comment: Kindly check whether
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721547/how-to-add-image-to-image-placeholder-added-in-pptx-using-apache-poi-api
helps you out

Comment: Thanks priya raj for your useful comment by using that now I am able to have image in my slide. But I want to add some new paragraph after the Image. Can you please guide me how can I do that?

Comment: Because In TITLE_CONTENT layout we can have only two shapes, And my requirement is to add more shapes in slide as per requirement

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/slideshow/xslf-cookbook.html#Text Can we consider this as separate frames so that we can add image, then paragraph and then image again. And also for more shapes, check it out in array index to be dynamic or fix to 30 so that you can add multiple images

Comment: priya raj from the given link I understood that I can create multiple text in PPT slide body, but finding difficulty to add picture and text both. Can you please share some example if possible. I guess that will be great.